# OpenApi Swagger 2.0 Hide Read-Only Fields on POST Request Method, but not GET

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, openapi

Is there a way to hide fields on a POST request, but not a GET.

For example, I have two API URI's that share the same resource name :

```
@Post
@Path("/foobar")
public Object postFoo(Object object) {}

@Get
@Path("/foobar")
public Object getFoo(Object object) {}
```

The Request Object in POST is shared with the Response Object in the GET.
I need to hide some read-only properties in the POST, so they only show for the GET method.

I have tried annotating with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = 'property1', allowSetters = true)` - This hides on the request, but not on the response, and cannot differentiate between http methods.

I have also tried annotating the setters.

The solution I have at the moment is just to explicitly add an `@ExampleObject()` in each of the required methods, but I feel there is a better solution somewhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated!